# Detecting whether the device is in silent mode or not in IOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios

How to know the device is in silent or in ring mode in IOS 5?

`kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute` gives `"RouteDetailedDescription_PortType" = Speaker`

But how to know whether the device is in silent or not?

Thanks,
Sai Jithendra

Answer (score 1):

`kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute` 
seems to be deprecated..Use `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteDescription` instead..
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki) thread

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Krishnabhadra.
BUT, in that thread there is no solution for detecting device in silent ! am I missed something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We won't be able to detect the silent switch state anymore since iOS 5...

The answer from Apple is there on the accepted answer : [Detecting the iPhone's Ring / Silent / Mute switch using AVAudioPlayer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki)