# AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord doesn't detect mute switch

Tags: iphone, switch-statement, avaudiosession, mute

I'm using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord to detect the user blowing into the mic since I want other sounds to keep playing. However, if the mute switch is on, I don't want any audio to play but I still want to record.

Obviously I could just use some IF-THEN logic and change it to AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord if the mute switch is on, but I'm having trouble detecting that ([from the looks of another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki), the solution that worked before doesn't seem to work on iOS5).

So my question has two parts:

1. Has anyone figured out how to detect the mute switch on iOS 5?
2. If not, is there a way to manipulate AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord to detect the mute switch ([According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryplayandrecord), AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord is not affected by the mute switch)

Comment: I think mute switch detection may have gone the way of the UUID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We won't be able to detect the silent switch state anymore since iOS 5...

The answer from Apple is there on the accepted answer : [Detecting the iPhone's Ring / Silent / Mute switch using AVAudioPlayer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki)