# How to mute an iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudiosession

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an iOS app switch the device to silent mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828958/can-an-ios-app-switch-the-device-to-silent-mode)

I am new to iPhone app dev, I want to put my iPhone silent mode for Ringtones and alert tones.
It is possible, because I seen in app "[AutoSilent](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8)"

Comment: Try refering the previous post of SO you will definitely get the solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304/how-to-detect-iphone-is-on-silent-mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158087/detecting-iphone-mute-switch-in-ios-5 hope this will help u....

Comment: I think its a repeated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828958/is-there-a-method-that-can-be-used-by-an-ios-application-to-programmatically-swi

Comment: @DShah - those links are about "how to detect", not how to set.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for this, as it effects things outsides of an apps sandbox.

Some versions of iOS are reported to have bugs, where if your app plays sounds in certain ways, this might block some alert tones.