# Detect ringer (mute button) position on iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, audio

I would like to detect the silent button's position (the button that switches the volume on or off). I'm making an app that plays a sound in the background, but I would like to detect if the ringer is activated so I won't play the sound. After all, if the user put his phone's volume at off, he doesn't want my app to play loud sounds.

By the way, I need to know the button's position for all iOS devices, not only iPhone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the phone's volume is off, your app won't be able to play a sound anyway so I'm not sure why it matters.

Comment: The volume is not necessary off when the switch is activated. If you have ever played some games on an iPhone, you know that usually it's possible to turn off the volume of the game by activating that switch. My goal is to detect the position of that switch.

Comment: Yes, but your stated reason is that you want to avoid playing a sound if the phone's volume is off...

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "if the user activates his phone's mute button", then I don't want to play sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8158159/1218712).

If you are making an app for jailbroken devices, you might want to take a look at [UIHardware](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIHardware).

Comment: I'm making a legit app, I don't consider jailbroken devices.

Comment: I have already read that thread actually, the code shown doesn't work for iOS 5. I clicked the link for iOS 5, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out [RDBMuteSwitch](https://github.com/Rich2k/RBDMuteSwitch).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make your sound be silenced by the mute switch, [configure your audio session to honor the mute switch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW1) by using either `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` or `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`.

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old post, but recently I found a good code in github https://github.com/Rich2k/RBDMuteSwitch and works very well.

This works in ipad with 7.1 (at least).

UPDATE: RDBMuteSwitch does not works since 8.2 and Xcode 6.2 instead I start used [SoundSwitch](http://sharkfood.com/content/Developers/content/Sound%20Switch/) and works fine with 7.1 or greater (i can't test with older devices yet)

This is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992452/detect-silent-mode-in-ios-7) where I found it.