# Detect silent mode in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

is there any way to detect silent mode in iOS 7?

the following code does not work for iOS 5 or later version

```
-(BOOL)silenced {
     #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
         // return NO in simulator. Code causes crashes for some reason.
         return NO;
     #endif

    CFStringRef state;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
    if(CFStringGetLength(state) > 0)
            return NO;
    else
            return YES;

   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect iphone is on silent mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304/how-to-detect-iphone-is-on-silent-mode)

Comment: all the answers are deprecated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check this thread - [Detecting the iPhone's Ring / Silent / Mute switch using AVAudioPlayer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki)

And this API - [SoundSwitch](https://github.com/moshegottlieb/SoundSwitch)

How it works:

- Play an audio file of 0.5 secs, every sec (after completion..)
- Check how long it took to play the sound
- Callback called real fast? nothing was played (silent switch is ON)

Enjoy!

Comment: Soundswitch API URL is dead

Comment: Hey guys, the sound switch demo page is back! get it here: http://sharkfood.com/content/Developers/content/Sound%20Switch/

Comment: It is not working on background, could you please help me how to achieve this in the background ? Please answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604629/audio-player-play-in-background-and-should-be-work-with-hardware-mute-switch

Comment: The link above no longer works. Here's the github version for a sample project: https://github.com/moshegottlieb/SoundSwitch

Comment: @iMoses, I've used your latest link to update the answer, but feel free to edit the answers and update broken links ;)

Comment: In case anyone needs a solution for .NET & Xamarin, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67326679/1014048).