# Get current system settings in iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, audio, swift

I am trying to **get the current system sound and vibration settings** that is set on the device, so I can change them, and reset them back to what they were after. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get System Volume iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255006/get-system-volume-ios)

Comment: Similarly, a previous answer for detecting silent mode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20992650/88111 Note however that the vibration setting (silent mode) is controlled by a hardware switch, so you can't set it programmatically.