# How to tell if the users phone ringer is off or on? Using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

What code do I use to determine if the users iPhone ringer is on or off?

The app I am making, plays music in the background, if the iphone ringer switch is turned off, then I want the music to stop playing.

My question is similar to this, but I want an answer in swift and IOS8...

[Detect silent mode in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992452/detect-silent-mode-in-ios-7)

Code:

```
if iphoneRinger == On {
  self.playmusic()
}
else {
  self.stopmusic()
}
```