# How can I detect whether an iOS device is in silent mode or not?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I've been looking for hours and I can't seem to find any API that explains how to detect whether an iPhone ringer is in silent mode or not. This is what I'm talking about:

[image: iPhone Ringer Switch]

Is there anyway I can find out whether an iOS device's silent mode is on or off using Swift code? I'm specifically looking for iOS8 and up since the iOS5 ones have been deprecated. Thanks.

Comment: Have u checked this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20992650/5362916

Comment: I have and the top answer said that Apple didn't build it yet. Yet I've seen Snapchat and other apps mute/unmute their video playback when the mute button is on/off. How do they do it? Also that answer was for iOS 4... @Uma

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think there is and you probably don't need to directly call an API to detect if the device is muted or not. What you need to know is this:

When playing a sound, you will do something like:

```
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory({AVAudioSessionCategory})
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
```

In the `{AVAudioSessionCategory}`, you can specify:

> AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient: Your audio is silenced by screen
>   locking and by the Silent switch
>
> AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayBack: Your Audio continues with the Silent
>   switch set to silent or when the screen locks

Comment: This helps a lot. It's not exactly the right solution I wanted but this can shape the way my app will work. Thanks so much Guy!

Comment: How would you detect that it is muted if there is a video currently being played?