# How can I get the ringer status / silent status of a device using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing a mobile application using Ionic and Cordova and would like to play a sound based on device `Ringer Mode status`.

Is there any way I can get to know the device Ringer mode status:

```
vibration
silent
normal
```

I found an example for Android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically).

Comment: Perhaps you will have to make plugin for that.

Comment: any guide to make a simple plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

The only plugin I was able to find is [this](https://github.com/Salesfloor/cordova-silent-mode) one and it is only available for iOS. I haven't been able to test it myself, so I would recommend you take a look if you are interested in iOS.

Unfortunately I was not able to find anything for Android. So I took this as a nice opportunity to look into creating my own Cordova plugin. I have not extensively tested it yet and it only works for Android, but I think it can be used as a starting point for you and others.

You can find the repository [here](https://github.com/RasimKanca/cordova-plugin-ringermode/tree/master). Please feel free to fork or contribute to the existing repository. The plugin can be installed by running the following command: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/RasimKanca/cordova-plugin-ringermode.git`. And you can use it like so:

```
plugins.ringerMode.getRingerMode(function(ringerMode) {
      console.log("The current ringerMode is:" + ringerMode);
});
```

This method will return one of these three options: `RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE`, `RINGER_MODE_NORMAL` or `RINGER_MODE_SILENT`.

I looked into doing the same for iOS, however there doesn't seem to be a official way of detecting the ringer status on iOS, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992452/detect-silent-mode-in-ios-7) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284722/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-ios-device-is-in-silent-mode-or-not). If anyone could shed some light into how this can be achieved on iOS, feel free to comment and I'd be happy to add it to the plugin.