# How to Handle Application Setting Sounds inside Application?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created Settings screen inside Application.In Settings Screen Sounds Switch option is there.I am clicking Sounds switch on that time application sounds will be on, sounds switch is off that time application sounds will be off.How to handle that application sounds in iOS swift.

Comment: show your tried code always

Comment: I don't have idea.First time only i am working on this Settings .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35285257/5255016 Refer to this solution. It might help you