# xamarin-essentials text to speech "speakasync" not playing audio in IOS device

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, text-to-speech, xamarin.essentials

It's working fine on android and iOS simulator, however when using an iOS Device(Iphone),  the audio does not play at all.

Comment: Hi, have a look at this [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50700/systemsound-playsystemsound-works-on-emulator-but-not-on-device), if this be helpful let me know.Or you can show code about it , I will check it.

Comment: It seems impossible to circumvent the silent mode, but you can detect it and notify the user about text-to-speech not working when the silent switch is on. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67326679/1014048).

Answer (score 4):

For the `TextToSpeech` to work properly on the Device the Ringer (button on the left side hand) needs to be turned On.

The **Speech** synthesizer in iOS is controlled by the **ringer** volume, not the **media** volume.

Hope this helps.-