# Detect silent mode in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to know if phone (`iPhone` or `Android`) is in silent mode using react-native?

Answer (score 1):

I found a [library](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound) hat has `getVolume()` method to retrieve the device volume. It has tons of other features so its big library.

If you just wanted to get the status try writing native modules yourself. Android has **AudioManager** class

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
        break;
}
```

whereas for iOS refer [this] implementation([Detect silent mode in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992452/detect-silent-mode-in-ios-7/20992650#20992650))

Good luck :)