# How to detect whether iPhone is vibrating or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-vibrate

I want to write an app that does something whenever the iPhone vibrates (receives phone call, text on vibrate mode). Is there anyway to detect whether the iPhone is vibrating (i.e. handle a "vibrate" event)? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not without jailbreaking, no. And definitely not for the 4.0 SDK. Can you even compile for that?

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't think so that Apple give so much liberty but still you can look here for a good discussion on this topic  [Detecting the iPhone's Ring / Silent / Mute switch using AVAudioPlayer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki)

Answer (score 0):

No.
You don't have access to any API that does this. Out of interest, why would you want to?

Comment: I want to be able to detect when the phone vibrates due to incoming message or phone call.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm curious what application this would have? Either way, iOS apps are sandboxed and your app has no access to this sort of system information.