# How to check vibration state is On or Off by pogramatically in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

How to check a system vibration is on or off by pogramatically through App? 
In my case UI design is like- I set a button into viewcontroller. Which funcanality is, when I press the button it's alert me the system vibration is On or Off. Here is the below code. But it's not working. It's always go with else part.

```
- (IBAction)checkVibrate:(id)sender {
 CFStringRef state;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);

if(CFStringGetLength(state) == 0)
{
    //off
    [self Alert:@"It seems that your phone's vibration is off. Please go to your phone setting and make the vibration ON"];
}
else
{
    //on
    [self Alert:@"It seems that your phone's vibration is On.If you want to off the vibration, please go to device setting and make vibration Off"];
}

}
```

If I go through wrong way,please help me out with this topic?

Comment: @user3182143 , i know it's a duplicate question. But I am trying to implement this topic through [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519807/iphone-how-do-i-know-if-the-vibrate-is-on-or-off-for-ios]. That time I am not getting exact output. So Please help me out

Comment: I added all sources below.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Apple is not providing the API to access this.

Comment: What I mean to say that, I want only check the mode of vibration(On or Off), not to want the change of vibration mode.

Answer (score 0):

Once I saw your question, I tried to get the solution.I prepared most of the other answer in the stack overflow and other sites.All tell to use [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession?language=objc)

> An audio session acts as an intermediary between your app and the
>   operating system—and in turn, the underlying audio hardware. You use
>   it to communicate to the operating system the nature of your app’s
>   audio without detailing the specific behavior or required interactions
>   with the audio hardware. This delegates the management of those
>   details to the audio session, which ensures that the operating system
>   can best manage the user’s audio experience.

Better Sources are

[How to detect whether iPhone is vibrating or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526585/how-to-detect-whether-iphone-is-vibrating-or-not)

[iPhone - How do I know if the vibrate is on or off for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519807/iphone-how-do-i-know-if-the-vibrate-is-on-or-off-for-ios)

[iPhone Vibration](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone%20vibrate)

[Making the iPhone Vibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)

[Detecting the iPhone's Ring / Silent / Mute switch using AVAudioPlayer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki)

Comment: Instead of posting a set of links to duplicates, vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok brother I will do.

Comment: @user3182143, Can you please help me out how to use AVAudiosession for checking system vibration is on or off instead of my implemented code?