# Is there a way to read the 'Vibrate on Ring' user setting in iOS?

Tags: ios, vibration

I'm seeking the value of the 'Vibrate on Ring' setting in iOS. It would also be nice to be able to read the value of 'Vibrate on Silent' as well. Does anyone know how to access these values?

Comment: Read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/6901363/468724

Comment: Thanks. That thread addresses the mute switch but 'vibrate on ring' is a software setting that can function when the hardware mute is off. My primary interest is in getting the value of that setting and I'm less interested in the 'vibrate on silent' setting or in detecting the state of the mute switch.