# Play sound when Silent Mode is OFF, vibrate when Silent Mode is ON?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I already know I can play a sound file using

```
SystemSoundID audioEffect;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) fileURL, &audioEffect);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
```

and how to restrict it to Silent-Mode-OFF-only using `AVAudioSessionCategory` and I also know how to vibrate the device:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

**But how can I vibrate the device ONLY when Silent Mode is ON (mute switch active)?**

Is there an "official" solution or do I really have to check the state of the mute switch using one of [these (kind of "hacky") methodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901363/detecting-the-iphones-ring-silent-mute-switch-using-avaudioplayer-not-worki)?